# Does the MVC3 ever look for an implementation of ITempDataPovider using IDependancyResolver?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

It's a pretty straight forward question. I'd like to be able to provide feedback to the user about the result of a postback using TempData (since it's auto-cleared). On successful execution of an action accepting a postback, I forward to a view dedicated to showing the result of the action, and would like to use TempData but leave SessionState disabled. For now the `CookieTempDataProvider` included in MVC3 Futures works great, but it doesn't seem like my implementation of `IDependancyResolver` is ever called to look for anything that implements `ITempDataPovider`.

Was this an oversight?

Anyone else tried this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depenency injection is not used to look up instances of `ITempDataProvider` in MVC 3. The DI work done in MVC 3 was meant to expose the most frequently requested DI seems.

The only way to customize the instance of `ITempDataProvider` is to override the `Controller.CreateTempDataProvider` method.

Answer (score 4):

you can do this by creating a new controllerfactory which is requested by IDependancyResolver

```
/// <summary>
///   <para>Controller Factory</para>
/// </summary>
public class MyControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory {

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Get instance of the controller</para>
    /// </summary>
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(
            RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) {
        var controller = base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);

        if (controller != null
                && typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(controller.GetType())) {
            // ITempDataProvider
            var tempDataProvider = DependencyResolver.Current
                                       .GetService<ITempDataProvider>();
            if (tempDataProvider != null)
                ((Controller) controller).TempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        }

        return controller;
    }
}
```

Then in your dependancy resolver set it to look for IControllerFactory, and return your ITempDataProvider

example for ninject:

```
_kernel.Bind<IControllerFactory>()
            .To<MyControllerFactory>().InSingletonScope();
_kernel.Bind<ITempDataProvider>()
            .ToMethod(c => new CookieTempDataProvider(HttpContext.Current))
            .InRequestScope();
```