# In MVC3, how do I override the TempDataProvider globally?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tempdata, post-redirect-get

I'd like to change the TempDataProvider in an ASP.NET MVC3 application... I know I can do this on each controller by overriding `CreateTempDataProvider`... but I was wondering if there is a way to do this in 1 spot ("Global.asax?") for all controllers.

My reason is that my site is on a cloud server... and I want to implement the Post-Redirect-Get pattern in some cases, but I don't want the user to be sent to another server and never get his message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you could write your own ControllerFactory. Here you could then, after retrieving the controller from the base `DefaultControllerFactory` class, set the `TempDataProvider` to your   implementation. See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332247/does-the-mvc3-ever-look-for-an-implementation-of-itempdatapovider-using-idependan).
This probably does what you need, but personally I would prefer more then next approach:

I find it a good practice to have all your controllers inherit from some **'base' controller** class.  Common controller logic (like overriding `CreateTempDataProvider` can then be done in 1 place.

Comment: In the next project you can do it from the start :)